# Problems with id's in Android using setText

Tags: java, android

I am having problems with a Grade Percentage Calculator. This project has two layouts and two java classes. The problem is with the `First_Screen_J` Java class according to logcat. This is what the logcat says:

> 03-13 13:31:24.869 2167-2167/com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                           Process: com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator, PID: 2167                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator/com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator.First_Screen_J}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x13
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x13
>                                                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)                                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)                                                                                                 at com.example.luke.percentagegradecalculator.First_Screen_J.onCreate(First_Screen_J.java:79)                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)

```
public class First_Screen_J extends Activity {

    int MaxInt;
    String number = null;

    private TextView TV1;
    ....
    private TextView TV24;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstscreenx);

        TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ....
        TV24 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            number = extras.getString("Number");
        }

        MaxInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
        TV1.setText(MaxInt - 1); // << --- Line Number 79 --- >>
        ...
        TV8.setText(MaxInt - 8);
        TV9.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 1) / MaxInt) + "%");
        ...
        TV16.setText((int) Math.round((MaxInt - 8) / MaxInt) + "%");
    }
}
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a problem with Strings, you have a problem with one of your resource IDs.. See your logcat!

Comment: @bdavies6086 Would you happen to know which one? Thanks!

Comment: To the close voters, please see the Error posted, the full stacktrace is there, just improperly formatted. Will fix.

Comment: Please remember unless you specifically have a question related to the Android Studio IDE, it isn't related to your question, so try not to tag it

Comment: I am nominating this for reopening because it should not have been closed in the first place, this question is completely viable and contains all relevant parts as outlined by the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing `TextView.setText` for tvs 1 -> 8

```
TV1.setText(MaxInt - 1);
```

The reason for this is that you are using

```
int x = MaxInt - 1;
TV1.setText( x );
```

From the [Android Documentation for setText(int i)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), `i` would be a ResourceID, a String definition from an XML file that would be referenced using *R.string.text_for_tv1* or something.

To solve this, simply use [setText(CharSequence cs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), turn your value it into a string by prepending `"" +`

```
TV1.setText("" + MaxInt - 1);
```

Or

```
 TV1.setText(Integer.toString(MaxInt - 1));
```

It would appear that you were trying to display the number `19`, which is the hex value `0x13` converted. The error was thrown because no string value was found in XML with the ID of *0x13*.

The remaining textvews will work fine because you have the `+ "%"` after the integer, had that not been there, you would have had the same issue.